# MySQL How to Optimize Sub Query Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I just created a table with:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_test` (
`time` date NOT NULL,
`line_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`location_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`placement_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`flight_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`impressions` int(11) DEFAULT `0`,
PRIMARY KEY (`time`,`line_id`,`location_id`,`placement_id`,`flight_id`),
KEY `table_test_IDX` (`time`,`placement_id`,`line_id`,`impressions`) USING 
BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Then when I try to execute a query:

```
SELECT 
  time,
  placement_id,
  line_id,
  SUM(impressions) AS totalImpress
FROM
  table_test
WHERE
  time BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-30'
GROUP BY time , placement_id , line_id;
```

It only took about 0.28s of execution.

But when I tried to execute:

```
SELECT
  daily.`time`,
  daily.placement_id,
  daily.line_id,
  daily.totalImpress
FROM
(SELECT 
  time,
  placement_id,
  line_id,
  SUM(impressions) AS totalImpress
 FROM
  table_test
 WHERE
  time BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-30'
 GROUP BY time , placement_id , line_id)
 daily
```

It took over 7s to execute.

What did I do wrong here?

Many thank.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT` for each.  What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Execution time isn't always the best metric for efficiency. (Weird, I know.) MySQL allows for query caching. This basically means if you run the same query repeatedly, it'll be significantly faster on subsequent runs. If you want to optimize your query, I suggest using the "EXPLAIN" command at the beginning of your query.

Comment: Running twice is sufficient.  If the second time is less than a millisecond, you probably hit the "Query cache" so it is bogus.   Avoid the QC by saying `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`.  Otherwise the second time is a good representation of having fetched data into cache in RAM.